# Powershell: Adding to and refreshing a datagridview on button click

Tags: winforms, powershell, datagridview

I'm trying to create a tool with a GUI that consists of a number of checkbox, up/down and combobox form controls that allows a user to:

- Select a value for each form control
- Click a button to "Add" all of the selected values to an array or object
- Add this object to a datagridview at the bottom of the GUI
- Allow multiple rows to be added to the datagridview on each subsequent press of the "Add" button

I'm struggling to get the values to show in the datagridview at all, let alone trigger a refresh when new values are added.

Here's some example code:

```
function add_Button {

    $obj = New-Object PSObject
    Add-Member -InputObject $obj -MemberType NoteProperty -Name DeployOK $chosenDeployOK
    Add-Member -InputObject $obj -MemberType NoteProperty -Name Name $chosenName
    Add-Member -InputObject $obj -MemberType NoteProperty -Name Cpu $upDown_CPU.Value
    Add-Member -InputObject $obj -MemberType NoteProperty -Name Ram $upDown_Memory.Value
    Add-Member -InputObject $obj -MemberType NoteProperty -Name AddDiskSize $upDown_SecondDisk.Value
    Add-Member -InputObject $obj -MemberType NoteProperty -Name OS $comboBox_OS.SelectedItem
    Add-Member -InputObject $obj -MemberType NoteProperty -Name VLANName $comboBox_VLAN.SelectedItem
    $global:Data += $obj

    Write-Host "Data is:"
    Write-Host $global:Data

    $dataGridView.DataSource = $null
    $dataGridView.DataSource = $global:Data
    $dataGridView.Refresh
}

$global:Data = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList

$button_Add = new-object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$button_Add.Location = "490,10"
$button_Add.Size = "80,20"
$button_Add.Text = "Add"
$button_Add.Add_Click({add_Button})

# Base form creation
$Form = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form
$Form.width = 1000
$Form.height = 600
$Form.FormBorderStyle = [System.Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle]::Fixed3D
$Form.Text = "VM Planner"
$Form.maximumsize = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(1000,600)
$Form.startposition = "centerscreen"
$Form.KeyPreview = $True
$Form.Add_KeyDown({if ($_.KeyCode -eq "Enter") {}})
$Form.Add_KeyDown({if ($_.KeyCode -eq "Escape")
{$Form.Close()}})


$dataGridView = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView
$dataGridView.Size= "950,150"
$dataGridView.Location = "10,400"
$form.Controls.Add($dataGridView)
```

The lines:

```
    Write-Host "Data is:"
    Write-Host $global:Data
```

Are just for debug purposes, so that I could check that $Data actually held the objects that I had created when I click the "Add" button, which it does.

Example output from the console:

```
Data is:
@{Name=; Cpu=1; Ram=1023; AddDiskSize=0; OS=Operating System; VLANName=VLAN-99}
```

...and on subsequent clicks of the "Add" button with different values selected in the form controls:

```
@{Name=; Cpu=4; Ram=3071; AddDiskSize=0; OS=Operating System; VLANName=VLAN55; ManualIntervention=ManualIntervention} @{Name=; Cpu=6; Ram=3071; AddDiskSize=0; OS=Operating System; VLANName=VLAN-10}
```

Any ideas? I'm new to creating Powershell GUI's using Windows Forms but have done some general purpose scripting in the past using Powershell.

Thanks

Comment: Hi 

Not familiar with Windows forms but i created something like you described with Jenkins and parameterized build

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to get this finished and working, so despite probably not being the easiest, simplest or most efficient, I decide on each button press to add the Individual properties of the object to the appropriate columns in the datagridview, which I also had to define beforehand. As an example:

In the datagrid definiton:

```
$dataGridView = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView
$dataGridView.Size= "950,150"
$dataGridView.Location = "10,400"
$dataGridView.AllowUserToAddRows = $false
$dataGridView.ColumnCount = 4
$dataGridView.Columns[1].Name = "Name"
$dataGridView.Columns[2].Name = "CPU"
$dataGridView.Columns[3].Name = "RAM"
$dataGridView.Columns[4].Name = "AddDiskSize"
```

In the button function:

```
$dataGridView.Rows.Add(,$obj.Name,$obj.CPU,$obj.Ram,$obj.AddDiskSize)
```

Then each time the button is pressed, the currently selected values in the form controls were added one row per button press.

Probably not the cleanest but I'm leaving this answer here in case someone is in a similar situation and need to get something working sooner rather than later.